# Showing that a property holds for all convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

> "$f(x)\geq g(x)$ holds for all strictly convex functions $f(x)$ and a function $g(x)$ with $g(0)\geq 0$ and $f(0)\geq 0$, because $x^q\geq g(x)$ holds for all $q>1$ and $x\geq 0$."

Is the above statement true?
If yes, can you give a source for it?

Thank you

PS: Thank you, Kavi Rama Murthy for your answer, which is a good counter-example. I now specified my question.

Comment: All functions $x^q$ with $q > 1$ are strictly increasing for $x > 0$ ...

Comment: There is no function $g$ such that $x^q \ge g(x)$ for all $q > 1$ and all $x \in \Bbb R$. Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: Now $f(x) = -1$, $g(x) = 0$ is a counter-example.

Comment: Oh my... Thank you Martin

Comment: Oh my... Thank you Martin. I am really sorry for being unable to ask my question correctly. I tried to simplify it, but by doing so I missed my whole point.

Comment: $f(x) = -1$, $g(x) = 0$ is  still a counter-example, it satisfies the added condition $g(0) \ge 0$.

Comment: It seems like I don't have my sharpest day :-( Final try, I also added a strictly and $f(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98613/discussion-between-paul-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the conclusion does not hold. A counter-example is 
$$
 g(x) = \max(0, x-1) = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ if } 0 \le x \le 1 \, ,\\
 x- 1 & \text{ if } x \ge 1 \, .
\end{cases}
$$
Then $x^q \ge g(x) $ for all $q > 1$ and all $x \ge 0$.

But  $f(x) \ge g(x)$ does not hold for all strictly convex non-negative functions $f$, e.g. not for $f(x) = e^{-x}$, or $f(x) = cx^2$ with sufficiently small $c > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not. For example $x^{q}$ is infinitely differntiable on $(0,\infty)$ for every $q>1$ but $|x-1|$ is a convex function which is not even once differentiable on $(0,\infty)$.